# Confused about how flags work in makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have 2 files: main.cpp which includes foo.h. I need a makefile that compiles them with the -std=c++11 flag but I don't know why the first makefile sets the flags but the second one doesn't.

Works:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
BIN=prog

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN) $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm $(BIN)
```

Doesn't work: (c++11 isn't actually flagged, so can't use c++11)

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11

all:
    g++ main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: You aren't using `CXXFLAGS` in any of your rules. You can safely remove `%.o` and let the implicit rule do its thing.

Comment: bit puzzled myself. My Makefu is weak after all these years, but shouldn't the `$(CXX) -o $(BIN) $^` be `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $^`to make the first "working" example actually work?

Comment: Your first makefile is using a default rule to translate `.cpp` to `.o`, and the default rule uses `$(CXXFLAGS)`. Your second makefile has an explicit rule to compile `main.cpp`, and it doesn't use the variable.

Comment: And thank you@Barmar for offhandedly answering my question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see, what part of the first makefile uses it? I thought (FLAGS) or (CXXFLAGS) had to be written but the first one works fine without. Edit: How can I set not to output a .o file in the first? The rm-f *.o for some reason doesn't delete it

Comment: @YesImhere It's not in the makefile, it's in the default `%.o: %.cpp` rule, because you don't have that rule in your makefile.

Comment: Ah OK, you don't have a rule in your first makefile to build a `.o` from a `.cpp`. So the implicit rule kicks in, and that uses `CXXFLAGS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your first makefile doesn't have a rule for making `.o` from `.cpp`, the implicit rule for this is used. That rule looks something like:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< $@
```

You can find all the implicit rules in GNU Make [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Your second makefile doesn't use this rule, because the `all` rule compiles `main` directly, rather than depending on `main.o`. Since you're using an explicit rule, you need to use the variable explicitly as well.

```
all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main
```